# How to add TomEE to already installed Tomcat7 - ubuntu server

Tags: tomcat7, ejb-3.0, apache-tomee

I have Ubuntu server with LAMP and Tomcat7. I want to add TomEE so that I can work with EJB. I don't see anything related to installing TomEE on a server that already has Tomcat7. What are my options? Do I need to uninstall Tomcat7?

Comment: All you really need to do is change the port of Tomcat or TomEE. They cannot both run on the same port.